# If cells contain certain number format then

Tags: vba, excel

I need code that will check cells in certain columns for the format of their numeric values.  I'm trying to do process optimization (ChemEng) but the time data often comes from the contractor in a useless format.

Basically I need a code that will function as follows:

Check all cells in row 1.  If cell contains word "Time" then... (up until here I can write myself)

...go through all cells in coloumn from row 2 to row x (assume x will be 15 if needed).  If cell's numeric value is in format **HH:MM** or **HH:MM:SS** then change cell's numeric format to **general** and multiply that value by 24.

Thanks a ton ahead of time! I've just had trouble finding any resources on checking the cell's numeric format.

Comment: Have you tried checking cell.NumberFormat value?

Comment: [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) is a wonderful thing.

Comment: It's always easier than you'd think.  Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop throw all the rows in column 1, and then check the number format:

```
For i = 2 to lastRow Step 1
If ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "HH:MM" Then
Do Something
If ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS" Then
Do Something Else
```

This should get you on the right track